# UIImageView in UITableViewCell low resolution after resizing

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiimageview, autolayout

I really got frustrated with auto layout and `UITableViewCell` stuff. I have a `UITableView` with dynamic heighted cells. Cells can have an image inside them. Image should fit to UIImageView's width.

Images are larger than UIImageView's size. So, after downloading the image, I resize the image and then put it inside the `UIImageView`. However, resizing the image with respect to UIImageView's width leads to low resolution as UIScreen's scale is greater than 1. So I tried to increase the expected size of the image after the operation (size= (scale * imageViewWidth, scale * imageViewHeight)).

However, this time, cell's height becomes 2 times bigger. What I'm trying to do is basically, while keeping UIImageView's height the same, increasing the resolution.

```
class ProgressImageView : UIImageView{
    func setImage(imagePath:String?, placeholder:String, showProgress:Bool, showDetail:Bool){
            if imagePath == nil{
                self.image = UIImage(named: placeholder)
            }else{

                if showProgress{
                    self.setShowActivityIndicatorView(true)
                    self.setIndicatorStyle(.Gray)
                }
                let placeholderImage = UIImage(named: placeholder)
                SDWebImageManager.sharedManager().downloadImageWithURL(NSURL(string: imagePath!), options: SDWebImageOptions.RefreshCached, progress: nil, completed: { (image, error, _, _, _) in
                    //resize image to fit width
                    if error != nil{
                        self.image = placeholderImage
                    }else {
                        self.setImageFitWidth(image)
                    }
                })
            }
    }
}

extension UIImageView{
    func setImageFitWidth(image: UIImage){
        let w = self.bounds.size.width //* UIScreen.mainScreen().scale
        print ("ImageView size:\(self.bounds.size) scaled width:\(w)")
        self.image = image.convertToWidth(w)
    }
}

extension UIImage{
    func convertToWidth(let width: CGFloat) -> UIImage{
        print ("Old image size:\(self.size)")
        let ratio = self.size.width / width
        let height = self.size.height / ratio
        let size = CGSizeMake(width, height)
        print ("New image size:\(size)")
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size)
        self.drawInRect(CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height))
        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return image
    }
}
```

As you can see in setImageFitWidth method, without UIScreen.mainScreen().scale it works just fine except the resolution and with the scale, UIImageView doubles in size. By the way, I tried all possible options of the content mode (aspect fit, aspect fill etc.) and I am using auto layout.

Result in low resolution:

[image]

Result in high resolution:

[image]

I want my screen to be just like in the first ss but with resolution of the image in second ss.

Comment: I really don't understand what the problem is; can you make your question clearer? Also, please can you include images that show the expected outcome and the actual outcome. I also don't understand what you mean by "increasing the resolution". When you scale an image up in size, the effective resolution will decrease (not increase).

Comment: @RoboticCat added screenshots with some fixes in description. Hope it is clear this time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size: size, opaque: YES, scale: 0)` 
to draw your image.
Scale 0 means the function will get the proper scale factor from the device.

Comment: Thank you so much, I assumed that if I double the size of the image, image view can adjust the image accordingly with aspect fit content mode but I was wrong. I know more about how UIImage and UIImageView work now thanks to you!